# Why i get an error while creating fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I try to create fragment and get an eror:   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900cb (com.example.myfirstapplication:id/fragment_container_view_tag) for fragment StationViewFragment{4187088} (0e8296cf-3a5a-4df1-b562-59b23f83018c id=0x7f0900cb)

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsqB7.png)
[Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yctrt.png)

Comment: Don't post images of code in your question. Provide the actual code

Answer (score 0):

1 Place frame layout in your activity where u want to open fragment

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Paste this code where u want to open fragment

```
Fragment mFragment = null;
        mFragment = new Name_of_fragment_which_you_want_to_open();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragment).commit();
```